# While loop with datetime functions will not work

Tags: python

For some reason, this while loop will not execute it seems. Can anyone help me possibly?
EDIT: the loop now works but now the alteration in the loop is simply returning an infinite repeating string of July 15, 0559

As for the purpose of this program, it is meant to calculate certain dates of the st. Habakkuk feast day, which is based on an interval of 256 days. It is meant to print the 0th, 10th, first 20th century fest day, and the upcoming feast day along with its ordinal value.
this is an incomplete code as of right now.

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
origD = date(559, 7, 14)
print(f"0th Feast day: {origD.strftime('%B'), origD.strftime('%d'), origD.strftime('%Y')}")
day = int(origD.day)
month = int(origD.month)
year = int(origD.year)

dNow = date.today()
yearNow = int(dNow.year)
monthNow = int(dNow.month)
dayNow = int(dNow.day)

daysToFeast = int(0)
whichFeast = int(0)

while not (day == dayNow and month == monthNow and year == yearNow):
    nextDay = timedelta(1)
    newDate = origD + nextDay
    daysToFeast += 1  
    day = int(newDate.day)
    month = int(newDate.month)
    year = int(newDate.year)

    if daysToFeast == 256:
        whichFeast += 1
        daysToFeast = 0

    if whichFeast == 10:
        print(f"10th Feast day: {newDate.strftime('%B'), newDate.strftime('%d'), newDate.strftime('%Y')}")
    if year == 1900:
        print(f"First 20th Century Feast day: {newDate.strftime('%B'), newDate.strftime('%d'), newDate.strftime('%Y')}")
```

'''

Comment: You seem to mix-up `+=` with `=+`. `=+` is wrong and will just do simple assignment. `a =+ 1` is the same as `a = +1`

Comment: the code wasn't working with it before like that and I guess I forgot to clean up my experimentation. while loop still doesn't execute at all though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean operations like `not`, `and` and `or` have [precedence rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) which govern which operations in an expression are applied first and to which arguments.

For instance, `not` has higher precedence ('binds' more tightly) than `and`. So your `while` condition in the above is actually equivalent to:

```
(not day == dayNow) and (month == monthNow) and (year == yearNow)
```

which will be `False` rather earlier than you intend...

Instead, you can group the expressions to make explicit your intent and to override the precedence rules, e.g.

```
not (day == dayNow and month == monthNow and year == yearNow)
```

Doing so allows the `while` loop body to execute, but reveals some other problems. The solutions may become obvious to you once you encounter them. Nevertheless, I would say your code could be significantly shorter and simpler.

For example, why bother maintaining separate variables for days, months, years etc. when the `datetime` module can step through days (`somedate += timedelta(days=1)`) and maintain that information for you? This would certainly make the `while` condition more readable (`not date1 == date2`), and might help you (and StackOverflow contributors) identify where the problems are coming from. Here is my attempt and making your code more concise, and which prints the 10th 'feast day':

```
from datetime import date, timedelta


then = date(559, 7, 14)
print(f"0th Feast day: {then.strftime('(%B, %d, %Y)')}")

now = date.today()
print(f"Today: {now.strftime('(%B, %d, %Y)')}")

whichFeast = 0

while then < now:
    then += timedelta(days=256)
    whichFeast += 1
    if whichFeast == 10:
        print(f"10th Feast day: {then.strftime('(%B, %d, %Y)')}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the rest of the code, the loop does not start because of

```
while not day == dayNow and month == monthNow and year == yearNow:
```

( that is the same of

```
while not (day == dayNow) and (month == monthNow) and (year == yearNow):
```

that always returns False )

try

```
while not (day == dayNow and month == monthNow and year == yearNow):
```